# AngularJS: Filter by regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, search, filter

I want to filter a list of elements by regex (user will type a regex in the input search field) using AngularJS filter.

I wrote everything that seemed to be necessary for me, but I can't manage to make the regex work correctly.

Here is what I've done so far:

View.html

```
<div ng-controller="listCtrl">
<input type="text" placeholder="search by any" ng-model="search.$">
<input type="text" placeholder="search by fist name" ng-model="search.fname">
<input type="text" placeholder="search by last name" ng-model="search.lname" >
<input type="text" placeholder="search by tel" ng-model="search.tel" >
<input type="text" placeholder="search by date" ng-model="search.date">
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users|regex : search as res">
           <td>{{user.fname}}</td>
            <td>{{user.lname.toUpperCase()}}</td>
            <td>{{user.tel}}</td>
            <td>{{user.date | date: 'EEE'}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="res.length < 1">
            <td>No elements found...</td>
        </t>
        </table>
</div>
```

app.js

```
...
app.filter('regex', function() {

  return function(input, property) {
   var patt;
   var field;
   var out = [];
   if(input === undefined || property === undefined) {
    return out;
  }

  angular.forEach(property, function(key, value) {
   patt = new RegExp(key);   
   field = value;
 });

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if(patt.test(input[i][eval(field)]))
      out.push(input[i]);
  }      
  return out;
};
});
...
```

The `listCtrl` will just add some elements to `$scope`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: FYI this has to be one of the slowest solutions to filter data

Comment: @Dalorzo could you give us a good solution to filter data by regex?

Comment: do you want to enter several regular expressions in each field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to call a function as part of your ng-repeat filter expression, ie.

then in your controller you'd have something like:

```
    function textRegEx(row) {
         var regex = new RegExp("row");
         return regex.test(row)
    }
```

This is for the entire row. You'd have to adapt it to work on just one of the fields. I posted a codepen earlier today here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOjdJV?editors=1010 with a dropdown for selecting the field you could adapt. Obviously if you're enabling searching on multiple fields you could concatenate the calls to regex.test into a single line.